# Error using tight layout with nested Matplotlib Gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a strange issue with Matplotlib Gridspec. I am making a plot with a nested grid, and I would like a tight/constrained layout to avoid tick label overlap:

[image]

My idea was to use tight_layout, which worked fine before I had the nested Gridspec. Now, however I call it, I get an error. Here's a MWE that replicates the problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10), constrained_layout=True)
grid = gs.GridSpec(8,5, width_ratios=[1,2,1.5,1,1], figure=fig)

a = plt.subplot(grid[0:3,0])
b = plt.subplot(grid[0:4,1])
c = plt.subplot(grid[4:,0:2])
d = plt.subplot(grid[0:2,2:])
e = plt.subplot(grid[2:4,2:])
f = plt.subplot(grid[4:6,2:])
g = plt.subplot(grid[6:,2:])

# create nested grid plot
nested_grid = gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(5,5, subplot_spec=c, wspace=0, hspace=0)
c.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
c.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
for k in range(25):
    x, y = np.unravel_index(k, (5, 5))
    gax = fig.add_subplot(nested_grid[x, y])
    gax.set_xticklabels('')
    gax.set_yticklabels('')
    gax.set_xticks([])
    gax.set_yticks([])

grid.tight_layout(fig)
```

The final line here is what's suggested in the Gridspec docs; previously, I wasn't setting a figure, and I just used `plt.tight_layout()`, which threw an error and led me to explore the Gridspec-specific `tight_layout()` method. But I still get the same error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1002aa79c5cf> in <module>
     25     gax.set_yticks([])
     26 
---> 27 grid.tight_layout(fig)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py in tight_layout(self, figure, renderer, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)
    412         """
    413 
--> 414         subplotspec_list = tight_layout.get_subplotspec_list(
    415             figure.axes, grid_spec=self)
    416         if None in subplotspec_list:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py in get_subplotspec_list(axes_list, grid_spec)
    247         if hasattr(axes_or_locator, "get_subplotspec"):
    248             subplotspec = axes_or_locator.get_subplotspec()
--> 249             subplotspec = subplotspec.get_topmost_subplotspec()
    250             gs = subplotspec.get_gridspec()
    251             if grid_spec is not None:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py in get_topmost_subplotspec(self)
    611         gridspec = self.get_gridspec()
    612         if hasattr(gridspec, "get_topmost_subplotspec"):
--> 613             return gridspec.get_topmost_subplotspec()
    614         else:
    615             return self

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py in get_topmost_subplotspec(self)
    483         Return the topmost `.SubplotSpec` instance associated with the subplot.
    484         """
--> 485         return self._subplot_spec.get_topmost_subplotspec()
    486 
    487 

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_topmost_subplotspec'
```

Note: I have tried using `constrained_layout()` with the `plt.figure()` call, which makes no difference (and does not work when I specify a figure in the first Gridspec call.)

EDIT: See answer below for the solution! Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem why you got this error is that the `subplot_spec` parameter type in `gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(5,5, subplot_spec=c)` needs to be `matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec`. But the type of `c` is `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`.

Change `c` to `grid[4:,0:2]` could solve the problem.

```py
gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(5, 5, subplot_spec=grid[4:,0:2])
```